# Joining python threads, sum totals

Tags: python, multithreading

My issue is I'm trying to loop over an array with a number of threads, each thread then adds the value into the global array. But for some reason the array is coming out as planned, I have noticed you need to use the join() thread function but am a little confused on how to implement it here

```
totalPoints = []

def workThread(i):
    global totalPoints
    totalPoints += i


threads = []
for i in range(NUMBER_OF_THREADS):
    t = threading.Thread(target=workThread, args=(i,))
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just write a second loop to join the threads

```
totalPoints = []

def workThread(i):
    global totalPoints
    totalPoints += i

threads = []
for i in range(NUMBER_OF_THREADS):
    t = threading.Thread(target=workThread, args=(i,))
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)
for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

Your code will fail at `totalPoints += i` because `totalPoints` is a list. You don't handle exceptions in your threads so you may fail silently and not know what happened. Also, you need to be careful how you access a shared resource such as `totalPoints` to be thread safe.

Answer (score 1):

does this help: ?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import threading
import time
import random

NUMBER_OF_THREADS=20

totalPoints = []

def workThread(i):
    global totalPoints
    time.sleep(random.randint(0, 5))
    totalPoints.append((i, random.randint(0, 255)))

threads = []
for i in range(NUMBER_OF_THREADS):
    t = threading.Thread(target=workThread, args=(i,))
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)

for t in threads:
  t.join()
print totalPoints
```

It always prints something like this:

```
[(1, 126), (10, 169), (11, 154), (0, 214), (9, 243), (12, 13), (15, 152), (6, 24), (17, 238), (13, 28), (19, 78), (16, 130), (2, 110), (3, 186), (8, 55), (14, 70), (5, 35), (4, 39), (7, 11), (18, 14)]
```

or this

```
[(2, 132), (3, 53), (4, 15), (6, 84), (8, 223), (12, 39), (14, 220), (0, 128), (9, 244), (13, 80), (19, 99), (7, 184), (11, 232), (17, 191), (18, 207), (1, 177), (5, 186), (16, 63), (15, 179), (10, 143)]
```